# .htaccess rewrite rule to change path to query string?

Tags: .htaccess

i want to rewrite URL like this

http://mysite/info/id show http://mysite/info/index.php?id=id content

can you please help me ?? i didn't find the answer in lot of sites

Edit:
i got the rule for that but what about this
mysite/info/game/id show mysite/info/index.php?game=game&id=id
?

Comment: that didn't help me it show 
Error 404

Comment: Did you try all the solutions, or just one?

Comment: Try this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: awesome that worked :D the problem was that i added / before index.php thanks Eda190

Comment: what about this
http://mysite/info/game/id show http://mysite/info/index.php?game=game&id=id 

??

Comment: Are you even trying to edit the rule yourself?

Comment: i am trying but i failed :P please help

Comment: Try adding another rule: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?game=$1 [L,QSA]` I have 0 knowledge off .htaccess files, and I only edited the code I found in other question's answer.

Comment: Note that if you are using relative path substitutions in the `RewriteRule` then you _must_ include a `RewriteBase` directive, otherwise results can be unpredictable. I think you need to update your question with the code you are using - this comment trail is becoming confusing.